# Serverless framework lambda execution role mismatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I am using the serverless framework to make a simple lambda based schema validation service with node.js and ajv library.

As stated [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/invoke#resource-permissions) my local invocations work, however when I invoke remotely I get an access denied from S3. Furthermore when I run the policy simulation on aws with my specific resource, it indicates that the access is granted and now I am confused.

I invoke my function remotely with

```sh
SLS_DEBUG=* sls invoke -f validate --data '{"schema":"valid", "schema_version":""}'
```

The relevant error message I get back is:

```sh
platform-sdk fetching: POST https://api.serverless.com/core/tenants/l1nxit/applications/api/profileValue
Serverless: Invoke invoke
Serverless: [AWS lambda 200 1.555s 0 retries] invoke({ FunctionName: 'validate-stage-validate',
  InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
  LogType: 'None',
  Payload: '***SensitiveInformation***' })
{
    "errorMessage": "Access Denied",
    "errorType": "AccessDenied",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:585:35)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
        "Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
    ]
}

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Error: Invoked function failed
      at AwsInvoke.log (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invoke/index.js:105:31)
  From previous event:
      at Object.invoke:invoke [as hook] (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invoke/index.js:23:12)
      at BbPromise.reduce (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:489:55)
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.invoke (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:489:22)
      at getHooks.reduce.then (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:524:24)
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.run (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:524:8)
      at variables.populateService.then (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:115:33)
      at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
      at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
      at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
  From previous event:
      at Serverless.run (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:102:74)
      at serverless.init.then (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js:72:30)
      at /Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:111:16
      at /Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:45:10
      at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
  From previous event:
      at initializeErrorReporter.then (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js:72:8)
      at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
      at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
      at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
  From previous event:
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js:61:4)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
      at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
      at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
      at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              10.17.0
     Framework Version:         1.56.1
     Plugin Version:            3.2.1
     SDK Version:               2.2.0
     Components Core Version:   1.1.2
     Components CLI Version:    1.4.0
```

The message I get back from https://api.serverless.com/core/tenants/[[my profileValue]] is `{"errorMessage":"Not Found"}` which is very suspect to me although I went back in my serverless user configuration and found no problems.

My serverless.yml configuration is as follows:

```
service: validate
app: api
org: l1nxit

custom:
  test: false
  inputBucket: l1nxit-schemas

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10

# defaults
  stage: stage
  region: eu-central-1
  user: serverless

# Lambda IAM Role
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - s3:GetObject
        - s3:GetObjectAcl
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.inputBucket}/*"

# packaging information
package:
  include:
    - node_modules/ajv/**
    - node_modules/fast-deep-equal/**
    - node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify/**
    - node_modules/json-schema-traverse/**
    - node_modules/uri-js/**
  exclude:
    - S3/**
    - __tests__/**
    - .idea/**
    - coverage/**

functions:
  validate:
    handler: handler.validate
    environment:
      TEST: ${self:custom.test}
      INPUT_BUCKET: ${self:custom.inputBucket}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get objects from S3, it is important to have permission to list the bucket you want to get the objects from. In your **iamRoleStatement**, add the permission to do so:

```
- Effect: "Allow"
  Action:
    - "s3:ListBucket"
  Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.inputBucket}"
```